# eclipse reference in buildpath that org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredplugins with no jar

Tags: eclipse, buildpath

I downloaded a eclipse plugin project that  [sharpen](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/reference/html/reference/sharpen/how_to_setup_sharpen.html). It has a refence in buildpath `org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredplugins` but with no jar. I search throuhg the internet but could'n find any jar with this name. Now I'm gettig error due to lack of required jars. I put screenshoot below

Can anyone help please

[image]

Comment: This isn't a jar, it is a special entry for the plugin dependencies list. It is normally shown as `Plug-in Dependencies` so there is something wrong with the project setup. How did you create the project?

Comment: I downloaded it. It's a eclipse plugin project here is the link http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/reference/html/reference/sharpen/how_to_setup_sharpen.html

Comment: Did you create the project or did you use the existing .project file? It looks like the project does not have the plug-in development `nature`.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the dependencies of this *OSGi* or ***Eclipse Plug-in* project** you need the ***[Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/)*** tooling (which is obviously missing in your IDE):

1. ***Help > Install New Software***
2. In ***Work with*** select ***--All Available Sites--***
3. Select ***Eclipse Plugin Development Tools***
4. Click ***Finish***

Similar to Maven dependencies are specified by IDs/names with version ranges in a specific file (Maven: `pom.xml`; OSGi bundle / Eclipse plug-in: `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`). Make sure all **required plug-ins** are **in** your **target platform: *Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform***.